# Process start but don't show the window

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to open an external executable. I can easily open external executables by using the `Process` class from `System.Diagnostics`:

```
Process p = new Process()
p.StartInfo.FileName = processName;
p.Start();
```

This works fine with most programs, like browsers and notepad, creating a process and showing its graphical interface. However, when I try to open my desired program, the process is started (can see it in the task manager, it even takes a whole CPU core for processing) but the GUI window doesn't show. What could possibly happen to a process from `Process.Start` to not show its GUI?

For reference, the program I want to execute is [ADOM release 60](http://www.adom.de/home/index.html), which runs 100% fine when I open it directly in the Explorer shell or in the Powershell. This is reproducible in both console and WindowsForms applications.

Here are some other settings that did not help:

```
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; // or false
p.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = /* any of possible values */;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true; // or false
```

Comment: Long shot, but does it require some command line parameters perhaps?

Comment: @NateBarbettini no, I can execute it normally on Powershell by just invoking the name `.\adom.exe`.

Comment: Does the process share a name with your programs namespace? Also, does it not work in the debugger only?

Comment: it appears that you are missing some code in regards to the following I would expect to see
`process.StartInfo.FileName = processName;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = commandLineArgs;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;` for example

Comment: Try to use the `p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false` and `p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute=true`

Comment: @TheApache don't do voodoo/cargo cult programming. There is no use setting properties to their documented default values.

Comment: @CodeCaster I know that the provided values are the default ones but just wanted to make sure the values are the same.

Comment: Are you trying to call this from a windows service or from console/GUI application?

Comment: Anyway you need to check the user which runs this process when you runt it from your application and which user is in use when you run it just as an .exe file (i.e. it needs 'run as administrator' feature).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to set the `WorkingDirectory` to the root folder where the executable is located.

```
var executablePath = .....;
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executablePath);
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(executablePath);
p.Start();
```

The default value of `WorkingDirectory` is `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32`. Many legacy applications have hard coded relative paths that resolve to full paths with said directory and will fail miserably when trying to read (or create) files where they are not supposed to.

Comment: Did not get this to work. My only new effect was that the console window that is part of my program wont close automatically after I close my form.